# Org mode M-RET not working with new builds

Tags: org-mode, version-control

Since the build of org mode of the end of august (now I use elpa/org-20150907), the M-RET does not start a new entry, and gives the error "Symbol's value as variable is void: org-planning-line-re". Strangely enough, M-SHIFT-RET still gives a new TODO entry.

I am currently on aquamacs emacs on OSX El Capitan public beta, but I do not think it is a system issue. In fact, if I go back to the aquamacs-bundled version of org (8.2.10, I do not know of which date, but I presume late 2014) M-RET works again perfectly.

Is anyone else having the same issue?

Comment: I installed version elpa/org-20150907 to check: no problem for me for both M-RET and M-SHIFT-RET. My OS is Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: So it seems to be a system-dependent issue. Then it is strange that the old version works with no problems. The two versions are installed on different paths, may that be a possible reason of conflict?

Comment: Seems like you are having similar issue to this one: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-09/msg00021.html - bottom line, this is likely a result of a mixed install: you have some bits of two different versions of Org together. The way to solve this is to clean the files manually and recompile.

Comment: Yes, deleting the base aquamacs installation and keeping only the new one solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: In this case it's best to first remove the old installation and to install the fresh one from blank slate. There are some known issues with trying to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

This issue might be happening because you are loading `org` package from system installation then loading it again from local installation (e.g. from a ELPA repository).

Double check if your have any `(require 'org)` before `(package-initialize)`.